# Spring boot data + Oracle = batch update of entities not working

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I am trying to do a batch/bulk update using the CrudRespositories saveAll method however it seems that it does not work. Generate log :

```
2020-05-23 07:06:27.963Z INFO  [nio-8080-exec-1] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener {} : Session Metrics {
    314694800 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    54054998 nanoseconds spent preparing 12 JDBC statements;
    5762126698 nanoseconds spent executing 12 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
```

I think `0 JDBC batches` means batch update was not done?

I have configured the following properties for batching :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=30
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.batch_versioned_data=true
```

Dependency versions:

```
Spring boot : 2.2.5.RELEASE
Oracle : tried on both 11g and 12c
jdbc driver :
<groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
<artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
<version>18.3</version>
```

Let me know what else needs to be done for this to work? If it doesn't work by providing these properties what are other possible solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue. I was using an older dialect i.e org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect which it seems doesnt support batching. I changed it to org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to use the [official JDBC drivers](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/) in your pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
<artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
<version>18.3.0.0</version>
```